# Python calling multiprocessing from separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, ctypes

I'm trying to call a multiprocessing function from a python thread to avoid the Global Interpreter Lock affecting my multiprocessing function.

The logic looks like this:

```
python --- ongoing python processing...
       \
        -> py thread -> py multiprocessing call ->  C-code (dll/ctypes)
```

Does this make sense? Will the C code run on a separate core, or is this too complex to work?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the reply. I should clarify, but I need to call on a second thread because I have to first make a python array and then pass the pointer to a C function. So I can't call the multiprocessing function too early (and also the main python processing needs to start and continue seamlessly).

**EDIT**: Here's the code logic and why I can't call a 2nd process inline with main code:

```
main():
...
p = Process(target=save_c, args=(...,))
p.start()
p.join()   #Main thread will lock here and wait until return;

#Other code that needs to be processed follows the multiprocess call

save_c():
''' Function which calls C-module '''
_sum = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/murphylab_picam/temp/libsum.so')
_sum.c_function.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
_sum.c_function(ctypes.c_int(num_numbers), array_type(*_sum.numbers))
```

What am I missing here? Is there a different way to use multiprocessing inline with ongoing processing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join immediately after you create a process as long as you don't want to wait for that process to finish before continuing.

This is the principle of concurrent programming.

Important thing is that you eventually call `join` or your main process will terminate leaving the child orphan.

```
child_process = Process(....)
child_process.start()  # the child process will start its independend execution here

do_some_stuff()
do_some_more_stuff()

child_process.join()  # here you are waiting for it to finish
```

Comment: noxdafox, thanks for the reply. I tried to clarify my original question, but obviously I can't just start a process in the main thread, this was the whole point of my question (which I didn't explain very well). Main python code needs to start and continue running while a pointer is passed to a C module - which then runs on a different core. It works well with just a thread call and then C call, but main python + C code then run on a single thread. I'd like for the C code to run on a 2nd thread. Tx

Comment: Not sure I understand, why you need to create that python array in a separate thread? You could just create it either in the main process before starting the child or directly at the beginning of the child execution.

Comment: Ok, I re-edited my answer to explain my confusion. As I've been using it,  main() waits for multiprocessing to complete, but I need the processing to continue. Is there something about pipes that I don't understand?

Comment: Hoping I understood what you're asking I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now.